# SQL - Find common rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table Wallets:

```
[id]   [address]

1      ABC
2      ABC
3      DEF
4      GHI
5      JKL
```

I have a table Cards

```
[company] [color] [wallet_id]

Facebook   blue     1
Facebook   blue     2
Youtube    red      3
Facebook   blue     3
Orkut      pink     4 
Microsoft  green    5
Facebook   blue     5
```

I want to get all the different wallet addresses that have the same cards, so if i pass wallet id 1, it should return:

```
 [id]   [address]
  3      DEF // Because wallet with id 1 and 3 have same blue Facebook card
  5      JKL // Because wallet with id 1 and 5 have same blue Facebook card
```

In this case it should not return Wallet with ID 2, even having the same card, because it is the same address (ABC) that we are doing the lookup.

I've tried a bunch of different solutions, but im confused on how to organize the SQL to do this.

> I tried going with:

- First select the wallet we want to lookup

  - `SELECT id, address FROM wallets w WHERE w.id = 1`
- Select all the cards of this wallet

  - `SELECT company, color FROM cards c WHERE c.wallet_id = w.id`
- Merge these two queries with INNER JOIN

  - `SELECT id, address FROM wallets w INNER JOIN cards c ON w.id = c.id WHERE w.id = 1 GROUP BY id`

> Now i need to merge the result of the query above with other wallets that have the same cards

... Here's where i cant proceed, im confused on how to do this :c

Answer (score 0):

Not the most intuitive of solutions but does the following work for you?

Since you only need rows from *Wallets* we can use a *semi-join*, first exclude the rows not required from `Wallets` based on the source *Id*, then correlate with *Company* and *Color* that exist when joined with `Wallets` for the source *Id*

A more elegant solution might be possible by using a lateral join, if we knew your specific RDBMS, however a semi-join will likely perform pretty well.

```
select * 
from wallets w
where not exists (
  select * from wallets w2 
  where w2.address = w.address and w2.id = 1
) and exists (
    select * from cards c
    where c.Wallet_id = w.id and exists (
      select * 
      from cards c2 
      join wallets w2 on w2.id = c2.Wallet_id 
      where w2.id = 1 
        and c.company = c2.company 
        and c.color = c2.color
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join 2 copies of each table like this:

```
SELECT w2.*
FROM Wallets w1
INNER JOIN Cards c1 ON c1.wallet_id = w1.id
INNER JOIN Cards c2 ON c2.company = c1.company AND c2.color = c1.color
INNER JOIN Wallets w2 ON w2.id = c2.wallet_id AND w2.address <> w1.address  
WHERE w1.id = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NY9t2rMY).